# Internet Explorer protected mode logging

Tags: internet-explorer, bho

How can I do this? I'm trying to create a low integrity folder but it still does not let me log to it

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very specific about how you are trying to create a low integrity folder.  However, you should be able to write to the C:\Users\\AppData\LocalLow folder (including creating a sub-folder within it) as the LocalLow folder is low integrity...  Hope this helps.